# iterate json data response using node.js

Tags: node.js

Am trying to get the key values from a josn response..

This is the response data obtained.from this i need to get the `projects` values

```
{ '$':
   { id: 'TP',   

     href: '/app/rest/projects/id:yuioTP',
     webUrl: 'http://teamcity.jffjf
' },
  parentProject: [ { '$': [Object] } ],
  buildTypes: [ { '$': [Object] } ],
  templates: [ { '$': [Object], buildType: [Object] } ],
  parameters: [ { '$': [Object], property: [Object] } ],
  vcsRoots: [ { '$': [Object] } ],
  projects: [ { '$': [Object], project: [Object] } ] }
```

code

```
var parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;
var async  = require('async');

var getJson = function(callback) {
    http.get(options, function(res) {
        var data = '';
        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        res.on('data', function(chunk) {
            data += chunk.toString();
        });
        res.on('end', function() {
            var output = {};
            var err = null;
            try {

                parseString(data, function(err, result) {
                    async.each(result, function(test, test_callback) {
                        console.log(test.projects)

                    }, function(err) {
                        callback(null, report);
                    });
                });
            } catch (e) {
                err = e;
            }
            //  callback(err, output);
        })
    }).on('error', function(err_) {

        console.log(err_, url);
        callback({
            error: err_
        });
    });
}

getJson();


 console.log(test.projects)
```

// Prints ....How can i get the object data inside the projects key

```
 [ { '$': { count: '9' },
    project:
     [ [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object] ] } ]
```

Comment: Have you tried `Object.keys`?

Comment: i dont know how to use that..i didnmt tried

Answer (score 1):

Using [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) method. Simple example below.

```
var a = {
  foo: "hello",
  baz: "world"
}

var array = [a,a,a,a,a] 

array.forEach(function(item){
  Object.keys(item).forEach(function(key){
    console.log(key + ' : ' + item[key])
  })
})
```

In your case you should iterate through `<object>.projects` and pass each item into `Object.keys` method

```
<object>.projects.forEach(function(item){
  Object.keys(item).forEach(function(key){
     console.log(key + ' : ' + item[key])
  })
}
```

I hope it will help you [`fiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/uh0w4gua/).

Comment: it returs project : [object Object] only

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
projects[0].project.forEach(function(item){

  console.log(item[0]); //log whole object
  var temp = item[0];
  Object.keys(temp).forEach(function(key){
    console.log(key + ' : ' + temp[key]); //log value by key
  });
});
```